# How to count each genre stored in 3 different columns?

Tags: sql, count, tableau-api

I have a home movie database, scraped from IMDB. The genres of the movies are stored in 3 separate columns (some movies only have 1, so the other two are NULL, while others have all 3 occupied).

For example:

```
Extraordinary Measures  2010    6.4 106 Drama                       Drama   NULL    NULL
Away We Go          2009    7   98  Adventure, Comedy, Drama    Adventure Comedy Drama
Repo Men            2010    6.3 111 Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller    Action   Sci-Fi  Thriller
The Ides of March   2011    7.1 101 Drama, Thriller                 Drama    Thriller   NULL
```

I want to create a visual in Tableau showing the number of movies from each genre I have from each year.

I was wondering how I could create a query which would return the number of each genre.

I tried using `GROUP BY`, and `COUNT`.

Also I was thinking about using CASE but I feel like it'd be really complicated and hard to keep track of, so is there some built-in function to help me with my issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please can you edit your question and show us a clear simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by combining all genre columns into one column using `union all` and then applying the aggregate function `count()` to the resulting dataset:

```
select year, genre, count(1)
from (
  select year, genre1 as genre
  from mytable
  union all
  select year, genre2
  from mytable
  union all
  select year, genre3
  from mytable
) as s
where genre is not null
group by year, genre
```